# Kafka stream not printing the value in the avro format

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka producer is sending the data in the avro format and I am reading that using avro-schema(SpinsAvro) and trying to print the stream to console.

But the output is coming as below:Key is null, but value is coming as some garbage.

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null , [B@200868f5
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null , [B@841bc92
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null , [B@302e9607
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null , [B@6f9139fb
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null , [B@cbdab3c
```

Here is the code:

```
public class TestStream {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    final String bootstrapServers = "kafka-XXX:9092";
    final String schemaRegistryUrl = "http://XXX:8081";
    final KafkaStreams streams = buildStream(
            bootstrapServers,
            schemaRegistryUrl,
            "/tmp/kafka-streams");

    streams.cleanUp();

    streams.start();

    // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
}

static KafkaStreams buildStream(final String bootstrapServers,
                                   final String schemaRegistryUrl,
                                   final String stateDir) {
    final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "lambda-example");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "lambda-example-client");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    streamsConfiguration.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    streamsConfiguration.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, stateDir);
    streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);


    final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    // read the source stream
    final KStream<String, SpinsAvro> feeds = builder.stream("spins_topic");
    feeds.print();

    return new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfiguration);

}

}
```

Comment: Are you also using the `KafkaAvroSerializer` in order to produce the Avro data?

Comment: yes..i am using  KafkaAvroSerializer 
Key -> StringSerializer
Value -> KafkaAvroSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect.

Kafka Streams used `Serdes` that are combined serializer and deserializer for a single type in one class. Setting

```java
streamsConfiguration.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
streamsConfiguration.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
```

does not have any effect. You need to use `DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG` and `DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG` and pass in appropriate `Serdes`.

Serdes for primitive types are already provided via `Serdes` class (e.g., `Serdes.Long()`). There is also class `WrapperSerde` that you can use to plug in custom serializers and deserializer to create a custom `Serde` (or you just implement the `Serde` interface from scratch).

Check out the docs for more details: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html

Comment: can i use specificAvroSerdo for DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE like       
     streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);

Comment: Sure. Check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroExample.java#L125